# How to enable parental control in specific user account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls

I have my laptop used by my room mates, I have a user account and everyone knows the password for the same. I don't want to put parental controls on my user account and want to create a room mate specific user account and set parental controls for specific things as below:

1. No Access to specific drive/ folder in the drive.
2. A installed software in my login available/non-available to other login
3. Limited usage of internet sites(I guess thats to be done in browser)

Just needed that much, :P hope no one gets mad on me. I tried to solve issue by my own but was unsuccessful in 2nd part. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we start you need to create a standard user account for your room mates.

> How to create user account in Windows 7:

Open Control Panel > Go to User Accounts and Family Safety > click on the Add or remove user accounts > click Create a new account > Enter the User name and make sure you select the account type as 'Standard'.

> No Access to specific drive/ folder in the drive.

You can do this by taking ownership and full control of the files and folders in Windows. To take a ownership of the folder/file, Right Click the File/Folder > Go to security Tab > Add your user account and remove the other login id that you don't wish grant acccess.

[image]

More detailed instructions and steps to take ownership and full control of file/folders are [provided here](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/18379-how-take-ownership-full-control-permissions-files-folders-windows.html).

> A installed software in my login available/non-available to other login

The built in Windows 7 parental controls feature can control which installed program can be run by the standard users.

> 1. Open Parental Controls by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, and then, under User Accounts and Family Safety,
>      clicking Set up parental controls for any user.‌   If you're prompted
>      for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
>      provide confirmation.
> 2. Click the name of the person you want to prevent from using specific programs.
> 3. Under Parental Controls, click On, enforce current settings.
> 4. Click Block specific programs.
> 5. Click Person's name‌ can only use the programs I allow.
> 6. Select the programs that you want to allow. If the program you want doesn't appear in the list, click Browse to locate the program.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Prevent-children-from-using-specific-programs)

> Limited usage of internet sites(I guess thats to be done in browser)

As far as I know Windows 7 doesn't have built in web filtering but you can install the [Windows Live Family Safety](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/essentials-other-programs) which is a free application from Microsoft.

**Web filtering using Windows Live Family Safety:**

> If you want to pick your own categories instead of using the preset
>   levels, you can choose Custom. You’ll see a list of all the
>   categories, and then you can choose what’s right for your kids. Under
>   Web filtering, you can also make a list of blocked websites or allowed
>   websites that will override the categories and filtering levels.
>
> Here's how to customize web filtering
>
> 1. Click Web filtering, make sure Turn on web filtering is selected, and then select a web filtering level:
> 2. Select Strict to block all websites that aren't child friendly or on the allow list.
> 3. Select Basic to allow websites except those with adult content and anonymizer websites.
> 4. Select Custom to allow and block website categories manually. To allow a website category, select it. To block a website category,
>      clear its check box.
> 5. Click Save.

**Here's how to allow or block a website**

> 1. Under Allow or block a website, type or paste into the box the web address of the website that you want to allow or block.
> 2. Select an option from the list, click Add, and then click Allow or Block. Click Save.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Protecting-your-kids-with-Family-Safety)